# Change orientation of buffer function

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need a function that splits a vector in smaller frames with an overlap, like `buffer`, but instead of column-wise, it should be done row-wise.

This is how `buffer` works:

```
x = 1:20
x = buffer(x, 10, 5);

x =  0     1     6    11
     0     2     7    12
     0     3     8    13
     0     4     9    14
     0     5    10    15
     1     6    11    16
     2     7    12    17
     3     8    13    18
     4     9    14    19
     5    10    15    20
```

What I want would be this though:

```
x =  0    0    1    2
     1    2    3    4
     3    4    5    6
     5    6    7    8
     7    8    9   10
     9   10   11   12
    11   12   13   14
    13   14   15   16
    15   16   17   18
    17   18   19   20
```

Is there any function or way to achieve that? Maybe combination of buffer + some rearranging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First figure out the answer in columns, then transpose the resulting matrix:

```
buffer(x, 4, 2).'
```

Comment: That's what I thought at the beginning too, but transposing changes the dimensions. It works in this particular scenario, although I'm still not quite sure why. If you do `x = 1:15; x = buffer(x, 6, 3);` then you get a `5x6` matrix, but I want a `6x5`, which you get, without the transpose.

Comment: With buffer(x,6,3), you're asking for a 6-element frame.  A 6x5 with row-oriented frames means 5-element frames.  What precisely do you want?  Is `buffer(x, 5, 2).'` what you're after?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite used to the notation yet. The idea is to split a vector into smaller overlapping frames, apply a window function to them, and merge them to a vector again. So my vector `x` should be split into, let's say, 6 frames. With the overlapping it will result in 5 elements per frame. `Buffer`, however, puts the numbers in columns, I need it to go row-wise, though. Is it clearer now?

Comment: In that case you want `buffer(x, 5, ?).'`, where the `?` is the overlap you want.  Overlap of 3 gives me 8 frames, overlap of 2 gives me 5.  The second argument to buffer is the frame size you want.  If this doesn't clear things up, please edit your question with a full example of what output you want from the 1:15 vector.